# Parsing a CSS stylesheet

Tags: c++, css, regex, parsing

I'm currently writing a simple HTML sort-of renderer for a learning project, but am currently stuck at the parsing part - kinda early, i know. I went with the "don't reinvent the wheel" approach, and am using TinyXML to parse the HTML file. And although drawing is kinda far off, i plan to use OpenGL for that. However, i ran into a lack of wheels for the CSS parser part. Is there any small, and reasonably fast CSS parser library available? If yes, can anybody point me to it? 
And if thats not the case - can anybody give me a *short* explanation as to what the approach would be for parsing a CSS file myself using C++?
Do i use regex's for example?

So, to summarize:

- Is there any small/fast CSS parser library written in C/C++ available?
- How would one parse an *extremely simple* CSS file, using regex's (for example)?

I by no means want to encompass a whole CSS standard, just the standard "by-id", "by-class" and "by tag" CSS selectors would be enough for now. I'm looking forward to something that might help me on my quest :D

Comment: What libraries are you using and what do you mean by fast?

Comment: frameworks as in what? Im only using TinyXML and TinyXPath so far, and plan to use GLEW/GLFW/OpenGL for drawing.

Comment: Ok, and do you mind using boost?

Comment: HTML is not XML, it may work/parse as such on test cases but in the wild it will not.

Comment: @Tim mmmh, well kinda yes... I saw a few parsing examples using Boost.Spirit, and although i am not contra-Boost i would like to avoid it, if possible.

Comment: @calcyss Alright, do you want it to be efficient or simple?

Comment: Well, arent HTML and XML syntactically the same?

Comment: @Tim simple^^ only simple

Comment: XHTML is (assuming its 100% correctly implemented) HTML is not, it just looks similar.

Comment: @AlexK. ahh i see what you mean now. Yes, there are a few problems that i see, for example, XML is way more strict than HTML. If i restrict the HTML files to XHTML though, it should be fine...?

Comment: @AlexK your comment literally came 1 sec earlier :P

Comment: Look at the terrible markup that is out there (HTML & XHTML), no XML parser will allow or be able to deal with it, HTML Parsers are very forgiving things.

Comment: @AlexK. True, but keep in mind this is a learning project, it doesn't need to render the www.

Comment: Oh well if you have control of the markup, correctly written XHTML will parse fine.

Comment: libxml can parse both well-formed and dirty pages.

Comment: Umm guys, can we please get to the question itself? Not that im not happy for all the help and insight, but i think ill handle problems with the parsing once i encounter them ;) i might just switch to googles gumbo-parser, which also looks great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would go with [LibCSS](http://www.netsurf-browser.org/projects/libcss/) as far as not reinventing the wheel. Which is a good thing. LibCSS contains a parsing and selection API, this makes it simple to combine it with the HTML parser.

However, writing a parser is also a good thing if where are talking about a learning project. I would recommend diving into [recursive decent parsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser). These are fairly simple to implement.

If I was to write a simplistic parser in psuedo C++ code, it would look like:

```
enum Type {
  ID, // #
  CLASS, // .
  IDENTIFIER, // [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_]
  LWING, // {
  RWING, // }
  COLON, // :    
  SEMI, // ;
}

struct Token {
  std::string value;
  Type type;
}

bool has_next_token();

bool has_next_token(Type type);

Token next_token();


Token expect_token(Type type) {

  Token token = next_token();

  if (token.type != type) {
    std::runtime_error("Error: expected another type");
  }
}

void parse() {
  while (has_next_token()) {
    parse_rule();
  }
}

void parse_rule() {

  parse_selector();

  expect_token(Type.LWING);

  while (!has_next_token(Type.RWING)) {

     parse_assignment();
  }

  expect_token(Type.RWING);
}

void parse_selector() {

  if (has_next_token(Type.CLASS)) {
    parse_class();  
  } else if (has_next_token(Type.ID)) {
    parse_id();
  } else {
    parse_tag();
  }
}

void parse_class() {

  expect_token(Type.CLASS);

  Token token = expect_token(Type.IDENTIFIER);

  std::string class_name = token.value; 

  // Do something with class_name
}

void parse_id(); // Almost the same as parse_class
void parse_tag(); // You know the drill

void parse_assignment() {

  expect(Type.IDENTIFIER);
  expect(Type.COLON);

  parse_value();

  expect(Type.SEMI);
}

void parse_value(); // I'll leave this one to you
```

Comment: forgive me asking, but can you - if possible and not too much work- provide a simple example for CSS? The sources for recursive descent parsers are wildly varying, one implementation heavily deviating from the other.

Comment: @calcyss I've added a simplistic parser example. You will need to fill in the gaps. Also note that I did not test it. Keep in mind that this ignores whitespace, you will need to skip whitespace in token functions.

Comment: well, wouldn't it be a good idea to just remove whitespaces immediately when im parsing strings?

Comment: oh, hold on. then selectors wouldnt work properly. haha.

Comment: @calcyss Indeed. For skipping whitespaces you could write something like  `while (source[pos] == ' ' || source[pos] == '\t') { pos++; }`. Add all space characters in the condition.